# Joomdle https:// access

Tags: joomla, moodle, joomla-extensions

Is https:// connectivity possible in [Joomdle](http://www.joomdle.com/)?

Joomla to Moodle HTTPS connectivity, as well as
Moodle to Joomla HTTPS connectivity and 
Joomdle Web Services work with the HTTP connection.

By default they provide only HTTP connection.

[http:// connection is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQalG.png)

However, if I put the https:// URL in the Joomdle connection, the connectivity fails.

Comment: In global configuration set it to https under server settings.

Comment: after that also it's not working

Comment: After upgrading the joomdle version Issue is resolved now.